# Windows: how to programatically query the registry to verify if ODBC driver is installed?

Tags: odbc, registry

I want to check if Cloudera's Hive ODBC Driver is installed in my machine.

Its registry key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC`.

[image: Windows Registry screenshot of registry key]

How should I check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registry key can be verified using the [reg query](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-query) tool.

Searching for a register key, the `/k` parameter must be used. So the following command will check if the driver is already installed:

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI /f "Cloudera ODBC Driver" /k
```

If the driver is present `%errorlevel%` environemnt variable will have the value of 0.